# How to perform integration of a number in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

[image: Integrating a_z with respect to t]

Someone please help me to integrate a_z as shown in the picture using Python2.7
Is there any predefined method to perform the action.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

for numerical integration.

In your particular example, a_z is a linear function of t and thus you dont need any numerical methods, you can do a symbolic integral and just compute the resultant function, which is much more efficient.
In fact, the solution is already printed there, so not sure what else you need to know?